# Pros and Cons of Sandbox delete vs refresh

Tags: sandbox, refresh, partial-sandbox

Our partial sandbox is out of date, and before undertaking a new project, our developers suggest deleting the sandbox completely and create from scratch instead of refreshing and renaming it.
Can anyone advise what are the pros and cons of sandbox delete&recreate vs refresh&rename?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting and creating requires either two licenses, or the loss of use of the sandbox (because you have to delete before creating to use just one license). Refreshing, on the other hand, requires just one license, and you don't lose access to the old one while the new one is being created. From a technical perspective, there's no difference, as the sandbox refresh procedure creates a new org, copies the metadata and data from the source org, then deletes the old org after activation. There are no pros to deleting and recreating versus refreshing.